# Picking Dynamic values from HTML form and store in PHP varibles

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I am doing online aptitude test, which will pick up 2 random questions from database and display them on webpage for answering.

Problem is that it's not properly storing values in the database (While Storing Questions and answers into the database it's getting jumbled up and some are not even storing). Can anyone please help me with this issue,

The code below is getting answers from candidate ( Simple demo picks up only 2 random questions).

```
<form id="form1" name="quest" method="POST" action="" >


<?php


  $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
  or die(mysql_error());
  $sel=mysql_select_db("demo");

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `microsoftq`  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2 ");

    rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $q1 = $rows1['QNo'];
    $qus1 = $rows1['Question'];
    $a1 = $rows1['Opt1'];
    $b1 = $rows1['Opt2'];
    $c1 = $rows1['Opt3'];
    $d1 = $rows1['Opt4'];
    $ans1 = $rows1['Ans'];
    echo " <b>Question:-<br></b>$qus1 <br><br>";
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q1' value = '$a1'></input>$a1 &nbsp &nbsp<br>"; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q1' value = '$b1'></input>$b1 &nbsp &nbsp<br>"; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q1' value = '$c1'></input>$c1 &nbsp &nbsp <br>"; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q1' value = '$d1'></input>$d1 <br><br> ";

    $rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $q2 = $rows2['QNo'];
    $qus2 = $rows2['Question'];
    $a2 = $rows2['Opt1'];
    $b2 = $rows2['Opt2'];
    $c2 = $rows2['Opt3'];
    $d2 = $rows2['Opt4'];
    $ans2 = $rows2['Ans'];
    echo " <b>Question:-<br></b>$qus2<br> <br>";
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q2' value = '$a2'></input>$a2 &nbsp &nbsp<br>"; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q2' value = '$b2'></input>$b2 &nbsp &nbsp<br>"; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q2' value = '$c2'></input>$c2 &nbsp &nbsp<br> "; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q2' value = '$d2'></input>$d2 <br><br> ";

}

?>

<input type="submit" id="submit_id" name="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Next part is storing them into database, after user clicks on SUBMIT button.

```
if (isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])) 
{
  $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
  or die(mysql_error());
  $sel=mysql_select_db("demo");

    $opt1=$_POST["answer$q1"];    // Problem is here

    $id1=array("$q1","$opt1");
    if($ans1==$opt1)             // Out Correcting answer part
    {
    $val1="ct";
    }
    else
    {
    $val1="wg";
    }

    $opt2=$_POST["answer$q2"];    // Problem is here

    $id2=array("$q2","$opt2"); 
    if($ans2==$opt2)              // Out Correcting answer part
    {
    $val2="ct";
    }
    else
    {
    $val2="wg";
    }
mysql_query("insert into $username values('$id1[0]','$id1[1]','$val1')")
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("insert into $username values('$id2[0]','$id2[1]','$val2')")
or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to post the question ID like this :

```
<input type="hidden"  name="q1" value="'$q1'">
```

Before

```
$opt1=$_POST["answer$q1"];
```

You have to add :

```
$q1=$_POST["q1"];
if (is_numeric($q1)) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `microsoftq` WHERE QNo=".$q1);
    $rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $ans1 = $rows1['Ans']; 
}
```

Complete code

```
// Build Form   
$nbQuestion = 2;
$form = '<form id="form1" name="quest" method="POST" action="" >';
$form .= getQuestion("SELECT * FROM `microsoftq`  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$nbQuestion);
$form .= '<input type="submit" id="submit_id" name="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT"></form>';

// Save answer
if (isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])) 
{
    for($i=1;i<=$nbQuestion;$i++){
        saveAnswer($i);
    }
}
function getQuestion($query){
    $question = "";
    $i = 1;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $question .= "<b>Question:-<br></b>".$row->Question." <br><br>";
        $question .= "<input type='hidden' name='q".$i."' value='".$row->QNo."'>";
        $question .= "<input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt1."'></input>$a1 &nbsp &nbsp<br>"; 
        $question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt2."'></input>$b1 &nbsp &nbsp<br>"; 
        $question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt3."'></input>$c1 &nbsp &nbsp <br>"; 
        $question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt4."'></input>$d1 <br><br> ";
        $i++;
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
}
function saveAnswer($nb){
    $qId=$_POST["q".$nb];
    if (is_numeric($qId)) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `microsoftq` WHERE QNo=".$qId);
        $rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $ans = $rows1['Ans'];
        $opt = $_POST["answer".$qId];
        if($ans==$opt)
        {
            $val="ct";
        }
        else
        {
            $val="wg";
        }
        mysql_query("insert into $username values('$qId','$opt','$val')")
        or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: hai its storing only $val, not $q1 and $opt1 values in the database

Comment: I have written code like this:   `$q1=$_POST["q1"];
 if (is_numeric($q1)) 
 {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM "microsoftq" WHERE QNo=".$q1);
    $rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $ans1 = $rows1['Ans']; 
 }
 $opt1=$_POST["answer$q1"];
 $id1=array("$q1","$opt1");
 if($ans1==$opt1)
 {
 $val1="ct";
 }
 else
 {
 $val1="wg";
 }`

Comment: you added <input type="hidden"  name="q1" value="'$q1'"> in your from ?

Comment: thanx its working fine if i take values from one table, if i take values from two table its again getting jumble.

Comment: like                                                               $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `microsoftq`  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ");                                                    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `linuxq1` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ");

Comment: hi thanx for ur time for writing complete code,. but ur code is throughing error like `Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htd,..` at line `while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {` and `Warning: mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\....` at line ` mysql_free_result($result);`

Comment: hi above problem is solved, but what is all $a, $b, $c and $d variables. I am getting error there `Undefined Variables` where are you using it,...