# Undefined Variables at $a, $b, $c and $d

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, forms

I am doing online aptitude test, which will pick up 2 random questions from database and display them on webpage for answering.

The code below is getting answers from candidate ( Simple demo picks up only 2 random questions).

```
$nbQuestion = 2;
$form = '<form id="form1" name="quest" method="POST" action="" >';
$form .= getQuestion("SELECT * FROM `microsoftq`  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$nbQuestion);
$form .= '<input type="submit" id="submit_id" name="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT"></form>';

// Save answer
if (isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])) 
{
    for($i=1;i<=$nbQuestion;$i++){
        saveAnswer($i);
    }
}
function getQuestion($query){
    $question = "";
    $i = 1;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $question .= "<b>Question:-<br></b>".$row->Question." <br><br>";
        $question .= "<input type='hidden' name='q".$i."' value='".$row->QNo."'>";
        $question .= "<input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt1."'></input>$a1 &nbsp &nbsp<br>"; 
        $question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt2."'></input>$b1 &nbsp &nbsp<br>"; 
        $question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt3."'></input>$c1 &nbsp &nbsp <br>"; 
        $question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt4."'></input>$d1 <br><br> ";
        $i++;
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
}
function saveAnswer($nb){
    $qId=$_POST["q".$nb];
    if (is_numeric($qId)) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `microsoftq` WHERE QNo=".$qId);
        $rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $ans = $rows1['Ans'];
        $opt = $_POST["answer".$qId];
        if($ans==$opt)
        {
            $val="ct";
        }
        else
        {
            $val="wg";
        }
        mysql_query("insert into $username values('$qId','$opt','$val')")  

        //$username getting from previous page, pls dont worry about it,..

        or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

i am getting error Undefined Variables at $a, $b, $c and $d.

Comment: Because you aren't setting them anywhere.

Comment: [It is best not to use the mysql functions](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: can you pls tell me how to display question options,.

Comment: Where did you get this code from?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119550/picking-dynamic-values-from-html-form-and-store-in-php-varibles/26119888?noredirect=1#comment40939977_26119888]

Comment: Notice, how in the code you had in that question, you used stuff like `$a1 = blahblah; $b1 = blah blah;` ? That's what you need.

Comment: i am doing the same thing but its not working,..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You no longer need to use those variables (based on one of your previous questions). Instead replace this:

```
$question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt1."'></input>$a1 &nbsp &nbsp<br>"; 
$question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt2."'></input>$b1 &nbsp &nbsp<br>"; 
$question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt3."'></input>$c1 &nbsp &nbsp <br>"; 
$question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt4."'></input>$d1 <br><br> ";
```

with this:

```
$question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt1."'></input>".$row->Opt1." &nbsp &nbsp<br>"; 
$question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt2."'></input>".$row->Opt2." &nbsp &nbsp<br>"; 
$question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt3."'></input>".$row->Opt3." &nbsp &nbsp <br>"; 
$question .= " <input type=radio name = 'answer".$row->QNo."' value = '".$row->Opt4."'></input>".$row->Opt4." <br><br> ";
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the posted code, you never output the variable `$form` which would explain why nothing is being displayed. In addition to that your `getQuestion` function neither outputs nor returns the variable `$question` causing it to in essence "do nothing". I would suggest adding this line to the end of your code: `echo $form;` and this line to the end of your `getQuestion` function: `return $question;`. I cannot however guarantee that these are the only revisions necessary in order for your code to operate correctly.